# Are my binaries portable across all x64 processors?

Tags: linux, clang

I plan to copy all my applications and binaries compiled on my Debian 10 Threadripper desktop to my Debian 10 laptops. Will those binaries run successfully?

I am currently running some sort of a Linux From Scratch system layered over Debian 10, in which I mean Debian 10 forms the base operating system, but the kernel is my own and Mesa, libdrm and libglvnd, and most of the applications I use, with their dependencies are built from scratch in *$HOME/Runtime*. The goal is to isolate the base system from 'my stuff' in a way Windows and macOS does to a certain extent.

I have 4 year old laptop that runs on Debian 10 as well; it's a Skylake i7-6500U with only 16GB of memory Now, I obviously do not have the time, patience or desire to recompile my entire so-called application environment on a laptop, so I simply copied *$HOME/Runtime* from my desktop over to my laptop's *$HOME*, making sure that i set up the laptop with the same username so that my applications don't complain. This works.

I'm now getting two low-cost laptops from China powered by Gemini Lake (N4100) and Apollo Lake (Atom x7-E3950) processors to install Debian 10 on since the Skylake is starting to fall apart with broken shells and hinges. My concern here is whether gcc, g++ or clang used any instructions specific to Threadripper (like AVX, etc) when it built my kernel, drivers and applications, because I'm going to be mighty pissed if my copied $HOME/Runtime fails to run in Gemini Lake or Apollo Lake because of that.

I ran *gcc -xc -v -* and  *gcc -xc++ -v -* and saw the following default flags:

```
-quiet -v -D_GNU_SOURCE - -quiet -dumpbase - -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase
```

Similarly for my *$HOME/Runtime/bin/clang -xc -v -* and *$HOME/Runtime/bin/clang -xc++ -v -* , where i saw the following:

```
-target-cpu x86-64
default target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

I do not pass any additional CFLAGS or CXXFLAGS to my builds beyond *-Wl, $HOME/Runtime/lib* to make the build link to my own libraries instead of Debian's, and *-fPIC*. Is this an assurance that my copied $HOME/Runtime will work on any x64 processor on Debian 10, as long as I make sure that they all have the same $HOME ?